# Replace variable in React Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got a strange one, this will probably be really easy for you guys...
I'm building a method within my component to generate HTML for an input.

So in my render I'm using `{this.generateInput('q1')}`

Below is my method, so I want question which is 'q1' to replace 'question' in the const and console.log below...

```
generateInput( question ) {
   if (this.props.next) {
     const label = this.props.question;
     console.log( this.props.question.props.details.form_label );
   }
 }
```

Comment: You mean you want to access `this.props.q1`, when `"q1"` is passed to the function?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just need to use bracket notation for property access instead of dot notation. `this.props[question]` would be the same as `this.props.q1` if `question` was equal to `"q1"`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech and saadq, that's worked a charm.

I just needed to do the following...
`const label = this.props[question];`